# Calculation of canonical orthogonalized basis from overlap matrix?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

From Equation [3.169] in David Cook's [Book](https://xn--webducation-dbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Oxford-Science-Publications-David-B.-Cook-Handbook-of-computational-quantum-chemistry-Oxford-University-Press-USA-1998.pdf) , I understand that we use eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the overlap matrix to calculate an orthonormal matrix using the formula $$X=Us^{-1/2}$$, where $U$ is the matrix of eigenvectors and $s$ is the matrix of eigenvalues for the overlap matrix. But, when I tried to calculate the dot product between two vectors from the new matrix $X$, I do not get $\phi_i\phi_j=1$ or $0$ depending on if $i=j$ or $i\neq j$. Does this mean that I have to normalize $X$?

Comment: What values do you get? If you re *not* getting zero for different vectors normalisation won't fix that. But to be honest without seeing your code it will be very difficult to say what is going wrong.

Comment: @IanBush I have posted the code in [Github Repo](https://github.com/HemanthHaridas/plank.py/blob/main/plankmain.py). The values were found to be close to 1.45. I did not post the code at first due to the size of the code (It is close to 750 lines now)

Comment: OK, I don't speak python, but normalisation won't fix not getting zero for different vectors - think about it, scaling one of the vectors by a constant C scales its dot product with another vector also by C, so the only way you can get zero is if the dot product is already zero, or C=0, and as the latter would give you the zero vector that is not allowed. Hence you should be getting zero for different vectors even if they are not yet normalised.

Comment: @IanBush I am currently reworking the code to check that I am not any mistakes in the code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is a pretty specific question, but essentially it lacks context and explanation of your thought process. Please Add a proper citation for 'Cooks Book' and it wouldn't hurt to just quote the equation either. Please also [edit] all relevant information into your question, this may include any code. I believe the character maximum is 16,000; so there should be plenty of room.

Comment: @Martin, I had previously provided the equation in-text, and I realize that it might have been missed in the first glance. I have since moved the equation outside as a separate block. I have also provided the link to the book that I was referring to. Just to add, I had also provided the link to the entire codebase, and did not post an MWE because it was not a standalone section.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a requirement that *X* had to be orthogonal. The only requirement was that $X^{\dagger}SX$ must be orthonormal.